# jQuery wrapAll : preserving hierarchy of DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have troubles trying to wrap an html tag around elements in the following structure :

```
<div id="xmlText">
    <a class="w" id="0">This</a>
    <a class="s" id="1"> </a>
    <a class="w" id="2">is</a>
    <a class="s" id="3"> </a>
    <a class="w" id="4">a</a>
    <a class="s" id="5"> </a>
    <a class="w" id="6">short</a>
    <a class="s" id="7"> </a>
    <span tagName="noun" id="8"><a class="w" id="9">sentence</a></span>
    <a class="s" id="10">.</a>
</div>
```

The elements with ids ranging from 6 to 10 are gathered in a jQuery object :

```
var $selectedText = $();
var $elements = $('*', '#xmlText');
for (var i = 6; i <= 10; i++) {
    $selectedText = $selectedText.add($elements.get(i));
}
```

Then, I try to wrap the following tag around these elements.

```
<span tagName="group"></span>
```

using

```
$selectedText.wrapAll('<span tagName="group"></span>');
```

jQuery looses hierarchy information.

Expected result

```
<div id="xmlText">
    […]
    <a class="s" id="5"> </a>
    <span tagName="group">
        <a class="w" id="6">short</a>
        <a class="s" id="7"> </a>
        <span tagName="noun" id="8"><a class="w" id="9">sentence</a></span>
        <a class="s" id="10">.</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

But this is what I get :

```
<div id="xmlText">
    […]
    <a class="s" id="5"> </a>
    <span tagName="group">
        <a class="w" id="6">short</a>
        <a class="s" id="7"> </a>
        <span tagName="noun" id="8"></span>
        <a class="w" id="9">sentence</a>
        <a class="s" id="10">.</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

I think I get what is happening but I have no clue as to how I could solve this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$('*', '#xmlText')` is finding **ALL** child elements, all the way down to the terminal nodes - e.g. you're matching grand-children, grand-grand-children, etc...

You probably want `$('#xmlText').children()` instead, which will find only the direct children of your `<div>` node.

Comment: Your suggestion works and solves my problem in this scenario. But I over simplified my problem : all the nodes don’t share the same parent. They are in different trees.